# DNS: if I delete @ A record, will * CNAME be honored?

Tags: dns, cname

Without boring you on details, my site's target must be set in `DNS` by hostname and not `IP`.

I have a `CNAME` record of `*`, but it appears that my `@ A record` takes precedence, so my `* CNAME` is effectively ignored.

Can I safely delete my `@ A record`? Will my `* CNAME` then be honored?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes.

Longer answer is that it DNS servers always give the most specific answer that they can and then will fall back to less specific. A way to verify that your CNAME is working is to query for an entry that does not exist on your DNS server. As long as you get an answer back then you can safely remove the A record and all will be well.

The A record will have a TTL (time to live). When you first delete the A record it will take a while for it to be removed from all caching DNS servers. This means that you will continue to get the A records answer for a while, once it expires then the CNAME will start being used.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will try it now. if it fails, I just put it back, so no harm.

Comment: bummer, that didn't work. I delete the @ A record, waited for propagation, then did an nslookup. I got Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find domain1.com: No answer

Comment: I just spoke w/the dns guy at the ISP. his answer was to create a proxy record, then delete the wildcard A and CNAME records.